# How allocate more memory to my docker container running the gcc command?

Tags: python, c, docker, gcc, compiler-errors

I have to compile C code which contains python function. I have a Ubuntu 19 64 bit machine and I need to compile the C code for my raspberry pi 3model b+ running raspbian stretch. To do that, I followed https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/109524/116139 to create a docker container with the stretch version I need. My docker `stats` are:

```
CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %                 NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
14b303f257da        DOCKER_CONTAINER   0.00%               13.68MiB / 7.776GiB   0.17%               6.51MB / 26.6kB     19.4MB / 41kB       2
```

Inside the container environment, running `top`:

```
    1 root      20   0 4241352  12308   4892 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.50 bash         
  133 root       0   0 4241096  12048   4972 R  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 top
```

In addition, running `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          30G   21G  7.6G  74% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1        30G   21G  7.6G  74% /etc/hosts
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /proc/asound
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/firmware
```

So, I gave you all the memories information about my system. My gcc command runs out of memory in compiling my large C code:

```
gcc -Os $(python3-config --cflags --ldflags) CCODE.c -o EXECUTABLE_CODE 

cc1: out of memory allocating 66660800 bytes after a total of 290631680 bytes
```

Running just the `gcc` command (without docker) in the RPi4 (4GB RAM) it works (while on RPi3b+, 1GB RAM, it fails reporting `cc1: out of memory`). However, I need RPi3 which unfortunately has a different OS.
I'm stuck in this problem for weeks. Does someone have any tips or different solutions? Thanks in advice.

Comment: A 32-bit ARM system without LPAE cannot address more than 4 GiB of memory. If that's the limit you're hitting, it might be easiest to try  cross-compiling. You could also use distcc if you don't want the trouble of fixing dependencies on your cross-compilation machine. I don't know enough about Qemu+Docker to comment on the maximum memory, how Qemu handles LPAE, how Raspbian handles LPAE, etc. You could also try adding a large swap partition to see if that solves anything.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @tttapa However I do not think it's the problem because the RPI4 runs a 32bit OS and in that environment the gcc command works fine. Anyway, do you know some good guide for cross compilation (which include also python.h libraries) for my rpi3?

Answer (score 2):

You could try cross-compiling your code to get around this issue.

For the toolchain, you can use [Crosstool-NG](https://crosstool-ng.github.io/). Getting Python to cross-compile is a bit more work, and I won't go into detail about it here. I'll refer you to the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/tttapa/RPi-Cpp-Toolchain/blob/master/toolchain/docker/merged/cross-build/Dockerfile) and [shell scripts](https://github.com/tttapa/RPi-Cpp-Toolchain/tree/master/toolchain/docker/merged/cross-build/install-scripts) I used. You can find more information about them [here](https://tttapa.github.io/Pages/Raspberry-Pi/C++-Development/Dependencies.html).

For the purposes of this answer, I'm going to use the Docker images I built myself. They are available from Docker Hub. You could of course build them yourself if you wanted to, the source is available in the GitHub repo I linked to earlier. If you don't need NumPy and OpenCV, be sure to comment all of that out in the Dockerfile, because it takes a long time to cross-compile.

The toolchain I used is for Linux 4.15 and later. If you use Raspbian Stretch, its kernel may be too old. It should work on Raspbian Buster and Ubuntu 18.04 and later, though. If you really want to use Stretch, you'll have to edit the toolchain config file as explained [here](https://tttapa.github.io/Pages/Raspberry-Pi/C++-Development/Building-The-Toolchain.html#customizing-the-toolchain) and build the toolchain yourself. The same goes for the Python version. By default, it uses Python 3.8.2.

---

#### 1. Prepare your working directory

Prepare a folder that contains all of the code you want to cross-compile. If you have external dependencies that you can easily move around, place them in the folder as well. We'll later just mount this folder to the Docker container.

#### 2. Write the build commands in a small shell script

Create a file `build-docker.sh` that contains whatever commands you want to execute in the Docker container to build your code.

```sh
set -ex
PY_CONFIG="${RPI_SYSROOT}/usr/local/bin/python3.8-config"
OPTS=$(${PY_CONFIG} --cflags --ldflags)
CC=${HOST_TRIPLE}-gcc
${CC} ${OPTS} CCODE.c -o EXECUTABLE_CODE
```

Notice how I used the `python3.8-config` script in the Raspberry Pi's sysroot folder. If you just use `python3.8-config` without specifying the full path, it'll use the configuration of the build machine's Python installation, which is not what you want.

You also need to specify the cross-compiler. Again, if you just write `gcc`, it uses the build system's native x86_64 compiler. You need the ARM cross-compiler.

#### 3. Run the script in the Docker container

Your working directory should now look like this:

```
.
├── build-docker.sh
└── CCODE.c
```

Now we'll start a Docker container with the necessary cross-compilation tools, mount the working directory to it, so you can access your `CCODE.c`, and run the build commands in the script we just wrote.

```sh
docker run \
    --rm \
    -it \
    -v "$PWD:/tmp/workdir" \
    -w "/tmp/workdir" \
    tttapa/rpi-cross:armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf \
    "bash" "build-docker.sh"
```

The first time you run it, it'll pull the image from Docker Hub, so it'll take some time (it's over a GiB).

When the build is done, you should be left with a file `EXECUTABLE_CODE` in your working directory:

```sh
$ file EXECUTABLE_CODE
EXECUTABLE_CODE: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3,
for GNU/Linux 4.15.18, with debug_info, not stripped
```

---

You can find a more detailed example here: https://github.com/tttapa/RPi-Cpp-Toolchain/tree/master/extra/python/cross-compile-module/spam

---

A small recommendation: If you write a lot of code that needs interaction between C/C++ and Python, or code that embeds the Python interpreter, [Pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) is a great tool. It has bindings for all standard C++ containers and Python/NumPy/Eigen types, it allows you to call Python code from C++ code, export C/C++ functions/structs/classes as Python modules, and it handles all compilation for you using CMake: https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example

---

*Edit:* If your secret CCODE needs to embed Python, you have to link to libpython:

https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#debug-build-uses-the-same-abi-as-release-build

> To embed Python into an application, a new `--embed` option must be passed to `python3-config --libs --embed` to get `-lpython3.8` (link the application to libpython).

```sh
OPTS=$(${PY_CONFIG} --cflags --ldflags --embed)
```

Comment: I followed your instructions and running your container 'docker run  --rm  -it  -v "$PWD:/tmp/workdir" -w "/tmp/workdir" tttapa/rpi-cross:armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf  "bash" "build-docker.sh"' it works in compiling pure C code (such as the classic helloword.c) and it runs on my RPi3, however compiling python code, converted in 'C' code with cython it fails reporting a lot of warning and one error 'CCODE.c:318:11: error: too many arguments to function PyCode_New'  318 |      PyCode_New(a, 0, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos). Do you have a solution? @tttapa
'

Comment: @Leo94 this is a known problem with Cython and Python 3.8: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2938

Comment: So, how could I compile my 'PY' code? A possible way could be building a my container similar to yours which has python 3.5? @tttapa

Comment: @Leo94 upgrade to the latest Cython version and generate the C code again. Why aren't you using setuptools to Cythonize and build your code? https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html

Comment: I already have the latest version of Cython on my Ubuntu machine, I built the C code from that. I need to protect my source code for that reason I need an executable. Any tips to solve the issue? Thanks in advice @tttapa

Comment: @Leo94 I've just tried it with Cython 0.29.16 and Python 3.8, and it seems to work fine. I've added it to the GitHub repo. https://github.com/tttapa/RPi-Cpp-Toolchain/tree/master/extra/python/cross-compile-module/cython What version of Cython are you using?

Comment: I installed the same cython version as yours. It still doesn't work reporting many warning '/home/develop/x-tools/armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf/lib/gcc/armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf/9.2.0/../../../../armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.bfd: /tmp/cc1q3cii.o: in function `__Pyx_copy_spec_to_module':
/tmp/workdir/CCODE.c:1221: undefined reference to `PyObject_GetAttrString'
/home/develop/x-tools/armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf/lib/gcc/armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf/9.2.0/../../../../armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.bfd: /tmp/workdir/CCODE.c:1224: undefined reference to `Py_NoneStruct'.Still not working @tttapa

Comment: @Leo94 if you want to embed Python in your application, you have to link to libpython, see the _edit_ in my answer.

Comment: It still doesn't work.It succesffully works for a simple helloword.py code, but with my large code i get `armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1 compilation terminated.` Do you know what could I do? @tttapa

Comment: @Leo94 make sure you don't have any memory limits enabled in your OS, add more swap, add more RAM, split up your code ... `armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf` is an x86_64 cross-compiler. It runs natively on your computer, without any emulation. If it fails, it's because either there's a bug in the compiler, or because you really don't have enough memory.

Comment: @Leo94 you can check the output of `dmesg` to check what caused your OS to kill the compiler. It's probably the OOM killer (out of memory).

Comment: I deleted that virtual machine but I suppose of yes, OOM killer. Any suggestion? How can I add more RAM? @tttapa

Comment: @Leo94 Allocate more of your computer's RAM to the VM, add swap, buy more RAM and insert it into an available RAM slot in your computer ... Or just split up the code into separate files and compile them separately.